# Is this a safe way to use a condition variable without mutex

Tags: c++, locking, mutex, condition-variable

My current code looks like this

```
void XXX::waitForUpdates()
{
    boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mutex_agentDone);
    while(!allAgentUpdatesDone()) {
        COND_VAR_AGENT_DONE.wait(lock);
    }
}

void XXX::onAgentUpdate(YYY argums){
    Agent * target = const_cast<Agent*>(argums.GetAgent());
    boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mutex_agentDone);
    REGISTERED_AGENTS.setDone(target,true);
        COND_VAR_AGENT_DONE.notify_all();
}
```

everything is fine, except when `onAgentUpdate` is called about a million times every 1 second, I have to worry about performance and optimization.

So I figured if I change the `wait(lock)` to `timed_wait` version that does the `allAgentUpdatesDone()` check, I can skip `.notify()`s which is otherwise invoked in the order of hundreds of thousands every second! Don't gasp, this is a simulation framework :)

Then I asked myseld:  what do I need the `mutex_agentDone` for? I can modify the two functions like this:

```
void XXX::waitForUpdates()
{
    //this lock will become practically useless, coz there is no other 
    // mutex_agentDone being locked in any other function.
    boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mutex_agentDone);
    while(!allAgentUpdatesDone()) {     
        COND_VAR_AGENT_DONE.timed_wait(lock,some_time_interval);
    }
}

void XXX::onAgentUpdate(YYY argums){
    Agent * target = const_cast<Agent*>(argums.GetAgent());
    REGISTERED_AGENTS.setDone(target,true)
}
```

The question is: is this safe?

thank you

A small note:
Assume that the rest of operations in the two functions are already safeguarded by their own mutex (`REGISTERED_AGENTS` is a class object having a `container` and its own `mutex` being invoked in every accessor and iteration method,  so `allAgentUpdatesDone()` is iterating through the same `container` using same `mutex` as REGISTERED_AGENTS)

Comment: Was leaving out the mutex lock in the second version of `waitForUpdates()` code a mistake? Because there is no `lock` variable in that code, and I'm assuming (sincerely hoping, actually) that `lock` isn't a member. Assuming you fix that, if `setDone` is atomic *and* the corresponding `getDone` predicate-check for the waiter is likewise atomic, you need not wait on the mutex in `onAgentUpdate before the set, but you still need to notify after the change. (all of that assuming I followed your code, which wasn't easy with all the abstractions).

Comment: @WhozCraig oh sorry, yes there must be a lock variable. it is a requred argument for timed_wait. thanks, correcting it now.

Comment: Ok. did what i said after make sense? It hinges on the atomicity of the get/set of that state member. if it is lock-free atomic then this can work (btw, you should be checking your result of your timed_wait). but you still need the notify if you want that cond_wait to arise by something beyond the timeout. Without that, it may as well just be a sleep.

Comment: What do you mean by "safe"? It's hard to understand your question. If your question is, "Can I use a condition variable as a silly way to release a lock, wait a specified time, and then re-acquire that lock", sure, you can.

Comment: @WhozCraig I *think* it does. by `state member` you meant the `lock` member right?

Comment: @rahman no. i mean the "done` state, but if you already have a mutex lock in the object protecting *that* than I'm in David's corner on this. I'm pressed to see what waiting on a condition variable unbound to a predicate is reallly good for besides periodic latching of the associated mutex.

Comment: @WhozCraig oic. ok, i got it, thanks very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
void XXX::waitForUpdates()
{
    boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mutex_agentDone);
    while(!allAgentUpdatesDone()) {
        ++waiters;
        COND_VAR_AGENT_DONE.wait(lock);
        --waiters;
    }
}

void XXX::onAgentUpdate(YYY argums){
    Agent * target = const_cast<Agent*>(argums.GetAgent());
    boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mutex_agentDone);
    REGISTERED_AGENTS.setDone(target,true);
    if (waiters != 0)
        COND_VAR_AGENT_DONE.notify_all();
}
```

The mutex protects the `waiters` count. Make sure to set it to zero to start.

You would expect the condition variable to already have something like this, but just the overhead to invoke `notify_all` may be significant.

This assumes most of the time there are no waiters. If the issue is that most of the time `allAgentUpdatesDone` returns `false`, then don't call `notify_all` unless *all* updates are done.

Comment: the last two lines of the code make more sense to me: why not just 1-have a `waiter` incremented in `onAgentUpdate` 2-when it reached a threshold, it would call `notify()` 3- `waitForUpdates` would reset waiter to zero after every 'wait' ?  is this what you meant?

Comment: @rahman It depends on the logic of your code, like what `allAgentUpdatesDone` actually tests.

Answer (score 2):

I am not very  acquainted with C++11 atomics but on Solaris you can use combination of volatile   bool and membar ops like this

```
volatile bool done = false;
void XXX::waitForUpdates()
{
//    boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mutex_agentDone);
    while(!allAgentUpdatesDone()) {
               while ( !done )
               {
                     usleep(1000000);
                     membar_consumer();
               }
    }
}

void XXX::onAgentUpdate(YYY argums){
    Agent * target = const_cast<Agent*>(argums.GetAgent());
    //boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mutex_agentDone);
    membar_producer();
    REGISTERED_AGENTS.setDone(target,true);
        done = true;
}
```

Thanks
Niraj Rathi

Comment: Although I am not familiar with membar consumer/producer, this looks like to be a solution. however, I wanted to know if my approach of using condition variables can be wrong or not?

Comment: Code is correct only thing is that mutex and condition variable services are provided by OS and sometimes they are   heavy in performance especially when it called multiple times like when mutex is not avilable process queue has to be reorganised, this is not case with atomics you dont overload the system. However improvement in performance will be minor as cache needs to be flushed.